# Android executable doesn't run on an arm9 processor board

Tags: android, arm, arm9

I created a sample Android executable using an Android.mk file and the ndk-build command. It runs successfully on an arm8 processor board. It doesn't run on an arm9 processor board. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hai\n");
return 0;
}
```

Android.mk consist the following commands

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := Test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Any logs available? Could You share the code?

Comment: it doesn't provide any log

Comment: So, how have You determined that it 'doesn't run'?

Comment: @sandrstar i put printf statement it doesn't invoke. i also provide my code above

Comment: What do you mean by ARM8 and ARM9? Do you mean Cortex-A8 and A9? or some older architecture based CPU?